# How to filter multiplication of a value in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want give discount offer for sale if the quantity 2 or its multiplication (2,4,6,8 etc ..) hoe to filter a value with this
my Query is

```
SELECT OFFER_MASTER0001.offer_type,OFFER_MASTER0001.discount,OFFER_DETAILS0001.offer_itemcode, OFFER_DETAILS0001.offer_qty,OFFER_MASTER0001.item_code 
FROM OFFER_MASTER0001 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OFFER_DETAILS0001 
ON OFFER_MASTER0001.offer_no = OFFER_DETAILS0001.offer_no 
WHERE (OFFER_MASTER0001.item_code = '0000010') 
AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty = 2) 
AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.date_from < '06-Mar-15 11:27:38 AM' AND OFFER_MASTER0001.date_to > '06-Mar-15 11:27:38 AM')
```

Here is quantity = 2, but I need all multiplication amount of the quantity.

Comment: Use [`modulo`(`%`)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276866%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: can you please explain that how to use with a where condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`modulo`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276866%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Change

```
AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty = 2)
```

to

```
AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty % 2 = 0)
```

The above condition matches all even numbers

Comment: What is the data type of `OFFER_MASTER0001.qty`?

Comment: that is  absolutely int

Comment: yeah i got you but my requirement is another 

AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty % 2 = 0)
the quantity is coming for the sales may be it will AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty % 4 = 0),AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty % 6 = 0) can u understand me what i accually need ?

"Sorry for my bad English"

Comment: Please give me an example of your data that my code wouldn't handle properly.

Comment: actually client requirement is  buy 2 get 10 offer for some products
if some one buying 4 product i need the same offer may be 6 8 etc..

|item_code|qty|discount|
------------------------------
1              |2   |10         |
2              |4   |5           |

this is my table and when selling 2,4,6 etc products for product 1 i should get the same offer for product 1

Comment: Then post a question / problem you **really** need help with in full.

Comment: yeah i got it i    changed this AND (OFFER_MASTER0001.qty % 2 = 0) to AND (2 % OFFER_MASTER0001.qty = 0) now everything is ok